# Good points in a triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have been trying to solve this problem with no avail . Please help

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. An interior point $P$ of $ABC$ is said to be good if
we can find exactly $27$ rays emanating from $P$ intersecting the sides of
the triangle $ABC$ such that the triangle is divided by these rays into $27$
smaller triangles of equal area. Determine the number of good points
for a given triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Con you get lines through A, B, C and 24 lines through BC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  three of the rays must pass through $A,B,C$ or you won't get $27$ small triangles. You would get $24$ triangles and $3$ quadrilaterals if none of the rays pass through a vertex of $ABC$

Comment: Therefore, I presume, the only good point is the centroid?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  no, there are rather more than that.

Comment: oo I think I got it is the answer 325

Comment: I agree with $ {26 \choose 2}=325$

Comment: @RossMillikan Hey, so I can see how it's $325$ (albeit as $\displaystyle\sum^{25}_{i=1} i $) but was wondering how you deduced that it's $26\choose2$. Thanks.

Comment: @Jam  It is a stars and bars argument.  You have to split the $24$ points that are not the vertices among the three sides, so you want the number of ordered compositions of three numbers (including $0$) that add to $24$.  Add $1$ to each to make it ordered compositions of three numbers (not including $0$) to add to $27$  Imagine $27$ stars in a line and select two of the points between them to break the sides.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, that's a really cool argument! I never did any combinatorics at school so there's a lot I've got to learn but thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: @Jam:  I got started with the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  It is a good one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the accepted answer is correct.  According to [this page](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/let-abc-be-a-triangle-an-interior-point-p-of-abc-is-said-to-be/), the answer matches the logic shown there.  However, on Project Euler [Problem 747](https://projecteuler.net/problem=747), the correct answer for N=10 would be 90.  However, the formula here would make it 36.  Also, the answer here does not take into account the types of divisions that the diagrams show. (In particular, some of the divisions don't have all 3 vertices with rays.  So based on the Project Euler data, what is the correct answer?